# When using Git how to make sure all people can use referenced dll

Tags: git, relative-path

I'm a Git beginner.
When using visual studio 2017 c# and Git.
How should one make a reference to a required dll, for a solution.
So that other people joining the git, but put their repro a different local computer folder, still can use the same dll's. Apperantly visual studio uses local path's, and i dont know how to make them relative.

Because if people would each alter the reference path i get lots of updates on that dll link, but every time someone corrects it for his computer then all others need to adjust it again.

Comment: git does not care about library loading. Only C# does. The answer to this question will be different depending on the language you use. This is not a git issue but a C# issue. You will have this same problem even if you distribute the source in a zip file.

Comment: where was i not clear that i do use C# ?

Comment: You tagged this as a git issue. The only tags are `git` and `relative-path`. I didn't say you were not using C#. I only said that this is **not a git issue**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference paths are relative so it will not be an issue.

One normally uses https://www.nuget.org/ for package management of 3rd party dlls. However, you can still add your own dlls and reference them by relative path.

For example, my csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\log4net.2.0.5\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

In this example, packages is a folder in the root of the git repository and the .csproj is also in a folder in the root.